# Glyphicons isn't rendering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

In my computer, running with Visual Studio, is working perfectly...

[image]

But, when I deploy it to my server, isn't rendering Glyphicons...
Any one knows what can be ?

[Site that isn't working](http://www.betasystems.com.br/leedinformatica).

**UPDATE**

That Glyphicons isn't part of Bootstrap, it's the original Glyphicons, downloaded directly from the site.

Comment: If you have used the Customizer recently, it may have produced a bad set of icons: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18474869/revisions

Comment: Nop, it's the original Glyphicons, downloaded without Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Load up your console - links to the icons are broken.